# Python Function with Lists and Sets

Tags: python, list, function, set

So I'm trying to figure out this problem and I can't figure out why it isn't working.

The premise is that you're given an input list and you have to find the second-lowest value. The list can have any number of integers and can repeat values; you can't change the list.

My code:

```
def second_min(x):
    input_list = list(x)
    print input_list
    list_copy = list(input_list)
    list_set = set(list_copy)
    if len(list_set) > 1:
        list_copy2 = list(list_set)
        list_copy2 = list_copy2.sort()
        return list_copy2[1]
    else:
        return None

print second_min([4,3,1,5,1])
print second_min([1,1,1])
```

The outputs for those two inputs are:

```
3
None
```

It's giving me errors on lines 9 and 13.

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list_copy2 = list_copy2.sort()
```

`.sort()` sorts the list in place and returns `None`. So you're sorting the list, then throwing it away. You want just:

```
list_copy2.sort()
```

Or:

```
list_copy2 = sorted(list_set)
```

`sorted` always returns a list, so you can use it to sort the set and convert it to a list in one step!

Comment: Sorry kindall, I read wrong what you said @kindall . I read it kinda fast

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sorted` instead of `sort`. `sorted` returns a new list, that is a sorted version of the original. `sort` will sort the list in-place, and returns `None` upon doing so.

```
def second_min(x):
    if len(x) > 1:
        return sorted(x)[1]
    else:
        return None

>>> second_min([4,3,1,5,1])
1
```

Answer (score 0):

*Help, I can't use sorted! It's not allowed!*

```
def second_min(li):
    if len(li) < 2:
        return None
    it = iter(li)
    a, b = next(it), next(it)
    next_lowest, lowest = max(a, b), min(a, b)
    for x in it:
        if x < next_lowest:
            if x < lowest:
                lowest, next_lowest = x, lowest
            else:
                next_lowest = x
    return next_lowest
```